# i was running my dynamic web project in eclipse. i getting this error why i dont know

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.servlet.FileCalling] in context with path [/ScfUploaddFile] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ejb.CreateException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at com.bs.theme.migration.loader.utility.QueryBuilder.doTFinvdtoQuery(QueryBuilder.java:355)
at com.bs.theme.migration.loader.action.manager.FGBDataMigration.main(FGBDataMigration.java:61)
at com.servlet.FileCalling.doPost(FileCalling.java:38)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

but if i run this same code in java console application its getting executed and i am getting the value in my console but when i run this same code by integrating it with my web application  it throws a error which i mentioned above

```
    public  String process(String message, int start) {
    System.out.println("from process method");
    String result = "Unable to Process";
    String ejbClientUrl = DBPropertiesLoader.EJBCLIENT_URL;
    System.out.println("Connecting : " + ejbClientUrl);
    try {

        System.getProperties().put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
         System.getProperties().put("java.naming.provider.url", DBPropertiesLoader.TI_EJB_URL);


        System.getProperties().put("java.naming.provider.url", ejbClientUrl);

        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        Object ejbObject = ctx.lookup("ejb/EnigmaServiceAccess");
        System.out.println("EJB Object : "+ejbObject);
```

QueryBuilder.java

```
                    public static String doTFinvdtoQuery(String table, String inputFile,
        String lowRange, String highRange) {

    Connection connection = null;
    String xmlToPost = null;
    Statement queryStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        connection = ThemeDB.getDBConnection();
        queryStatement = connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("****Generating Query****" + "\n");
        String query = getQuery(table, inputFile, lowRange, highRange);

        resultSet = queryStatement.executeQuery(query);
        BeanProcessor bp = new BeanProcessor();
        List<ServiceRequest> sRequestItems = new ArrayList<ServiceRequest>();
        String finalResult = "Unable to Process";

        int num = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (resultSet.next()) {

            try {

                num++;
                count = resultSet.getInt("SNO");

                ArrayList<InvoiceCustomer> list = new ArrayList<InvoiceCustomer>();
                list.add((InvoiceCustomer) bp.toBean(resultSet, InvoiceCustomer.class));

                TFinvdtoHandler tfinv = new TFinvdtoHandler();
                sRequestItems.add(tfinv
                        .createTFinvdtoRequest(list));
                if (num % 1 == 0) {

                    xmlToPost = MessageUtil.xmlServiceRequest(
                            sRequestItems, "TFINVNEW");
                    logger.debug(xmlToPost);

                    System.out
                            .println("**Sending data to TI Plus through EJB Client***"
                                    + "\n");
                    finalResult = TIPlusEJBClient.process(xmlToPost, count);

                    if (!finalResult.equals("Unable to Process")) {

                        List<ServiceResponse> serviceResponses = MessageUtil
                                .processResponse(finalResult);
                        for (ServiceResponse serviceResponse : serviceResponses) {
                            // System.out.println("**Response Status***"
                            // +serviceResponse.getResponseHeader().getStatus());
                            // System.out.println("**Response CorrID***"
                            // +serviceResponse.getResponseHeader().getStatus());

                            MigrationUtil.updateMigrationDataStagingStatus(
                                    table, serviceResponse
                                            .getResponseHeader()
                                            .getStatus(), serviceResponse
                                            .getResponseHeader()
                                            .getCorrelationId(),
                                    serviceResponse.getResponseHeader()
                                            .getDetails().getError()
                                            .toString());
                        }

                    }
                    logger.debug("\n");
                    sRequestItems = new ArrayList<ServiceRequest>();
                    finalResult = "Unable to Process";
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                logger.debug("Exception Occured ->" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();

        logger.debug("Exception Occured ->" + e1.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        logger.debug("Exception Occured ->" + e1.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("Exception Occured ->" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {

        MigrationUtil.surrenderConnection(connection, resultSet,
                queryStatement);

    }

    /*
     * System.out.println("Remaining request count ->" +
     * sRequestItems.size()); if (sRequestItems.size() > 0) {
     * 
     * xmlToPost = MessageUtil .xmlServiceRequest(sRequestItems,
     * "TFILCDTO"); logger.debug(xmlToPost); finalResult =
     * TIPlusEJBClient.process(xmlToPost, count);
     * 
     * System.out
     * .println("**Sending remaining data to TI Plus through EJB Client***"
     * + "\n"); if (!finalResult.equals("Unable to Process")) {
     * 
     * List<ServiceResponse> serviceResponses = MessageUtil
     * .processResponse(finalResult); for (ServiceResponse serviceResponse :
     * serviceResponses) { // System.out.println("**Response Status***" //
     * +serviceResponse.getResponseHeader().getStatus()); //
     * System.out.println("**Response CorrID***" //
     * +serviceResponse.getResponseHeader().getStatus());
     * 
     * MigrationUtil.updateMigrationDataStagingStatus(table,
     * serviceResponse.getResponseHeader().getStatus(),
     * serviceResponse.getResponseHeader() .getCorrelationId(),
     * serviceResponse .getResponseHeader().getDetails()
     * .getError().toString()); }
     * 
     * }
     * 
     * logger.debug("\n");
     * 
     * }
     */

    return xmlToPost;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run your project on WebSphere, Tomcat or stand alone? You have to describe what you are trying to do, as it is not clear.

Comment: Actually It was working in stand alone perfectly. But i want to run this in websphere and Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Library -> Server Runtime - > Click Next -> choose your EJB container

Comment: we could find any ejb container on the path which u have mentioned

Comment: what is your QueryBuilder.java:355 line

Comment: AFTER ADDING EJB JAR I AM GETING THIS ERROR javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory]
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:657)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:175)

Comment: You have to find jar contains this class com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory and add to classpath like you did for javax.ejb....

Answer (score 0):

It will run without any issues as web application in WebSphere.

If you want to run it from Tomcat you will need to add following jars to your application, but only for Tomcat: `com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_x.y.z.jar` and `com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar`. You should also review this page [Running the IBM Thin Client for Enterprise JavaBeans](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tcli_ejbthinclient.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-17-0-3&lang=en), as you may have later issues with SSL, if your WebSphere is secured.